# Scroll bar indicator visibility in sencha touch 2

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on Sencha touch 2. I have a tab panel inside which I have many tabs horizontally placed. I want to show the horizontal scroll bar always so that the user will know there are more tabs. 
This is my tab panel with tabBar configuration. How can I make the scroll bar indicator visible always?:

```
Ext.define('Project.view.Result', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
id:'searchTab',
    tabBar: {

         scrollable:'horizontal',
         scrollBar:'true',
         docked:'top',
         layout: {
                    pack: 'center',
                 },

    },
items:[
                               {  
                        title: 'A Result',
                        xtype:'AList'
                    },
                    { 
                        title: 'B Result',
                        xtype:'BList' 
                    },

                                ......
                                ......
                               { 
                        title: 'Z Result',
                        xtype:'ZList' 
                    }
                ]
        });
```

I tried this with css:

```
#searchTab .x-scroll-indicator[style] {
opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

But then the scroll bar becomes visible for the list items under each tab . But not for the tab bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You nearly got it just change your css to this:

```
.x-tabpanel .x-scroll-indicator {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is a good fix (worked for Chrome) but the scrollbars still don't show up all the time on Android WebView (Jellybean 4.2). I think this is because the CSS support for WebView is generally pretty poor. However, if you tap and scroll a list, then the scroll bar comes (rather ugly looking though). Just for anyone who is wondering.

Answer (score 1):

> "New in Touch 2.3.0, each indicator has an autoHide configuration that
>   allows you to control it. Setting autoHide to false will tell that
>   indicator not to auto-hide. You can use the indicators config within
>   the scrollable config on a Container or subclass."
>
> http://www.sencha.com/blog/top-support-tips-march-2014

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'container',
            html: 'The y scroll indicator will always show, x will hide as autoHide defaults to true',
            scrollable: {
                direction: 'both',
                indicators: {
                    y: {
                        autoHide: false
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1u9